# How can I use a ref callback function on a component this is connect to the redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to use a callback function on a few refs I've created that will then dispatch an action to the redux store. The problem I'm running into is that when I try to use the callback I get an error saying that the function I'm trying to call within the callback is not a function. I assume this is because when I pass the child component into connect()() it looses it's original binding. Is there a solution to my problem?

```
//callback

sumbitQuiz = () => {

      this.state.words.forEach((word) => {
          return this[word].current.compairWordAndHeldWord()
        })

    }
```

```
//Function in child ref I'm trying to call

compairWordAndHeldWord = () => {
        if( this.state.word === this.state.inputWord) {
            this.setState(() => ({ 
                wordAndInputWordMatch: true
             }))
             this.props.dispatch(addCorrectAnswer())
        } else {
            this.setState(() => ({ 
                wordAndInputWordMatch: false
             }))
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a way to do this i modify your `addCorrectAnswer` in order to return a promise from it, then (ehehe) you can handle the flow by:

```
      compairWordAndHeldWord = () => {
        if( this.state.word === this.state.inputWord) {
            this.setState(() => ({ 
                wordAndInputWordMatch: true
             }))
             this.props.dispatch(addCorrectAnswer())
             .then(()=>{
              //put here your callback logic
              }
             .catch(()=>{})
        } else {
            this.setState(() => ({ 
                wordAndInputWordMatch: false
             }))
        }
      }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to put in the promise. Shouldn't my callback logic go in the parent component, since I'm using it to call the compairWordAndHeldWord function?